# What's the difference between AsyncFunction().GetAwaiter().GetResult() and Task.Run(() => AsyncFunction).GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I try to understand the concept between `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. I know that it shouldn't be used if possible but I cannot use async/await in this case so I must get the result from an asynchronous function in a synchronous matter.

Let's consider this simple Blazor server app:

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask">Task GetAwaiter().GetResult()</button>
<button @onclick="GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction">Function GetAwaiter().GetResult()</button>

<p>@_message</p>
@code {

    private string _message;
    private async Task<string> AsyncFunction(string message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);

        return message;
    }

    private void GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask()
    {
        _message = Task.Run(() => AsyncFunction("Message from GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private void GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction()
    {
        _message = AsyncFunction("Message from GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Calling the function `GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction` will result in a deadlock. However when I call `GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask` it does not.

What is the key difference between those to functions? Why does it not results in a deadlock when called on `Task.Run`?

Comment: Because `GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction` runs [on your thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), whereas `GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask` runs on another.

Comment: Both calls are bad by the way. Make the methods asynchronous instead. There's a reason Blazor Server uses async methods extensively. *Every* call that modifies state and the UI is a async call from the server to the browser. By blocking the way you do you're wasting threads that could be used to serve other requests

Comment: `I cannot use async/await in this case` why? What  case is this? Blazor, especially Blazor Server, uses `async` extensively to the point that *not* using async is harder than using it. Why don't you use an asynchronous event callback? The [event handling docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) show just that: `button @onclick="UpdateHeading"` and `private async Task UpdateHeading()`

Comment: This blog post may shed some light to the problem: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Async validation is not yet supported within ASP.NET Core. That's why I can't use async await.

Comment: I'll need to check something within the database within validation. But the database access is only asynchronous available.

Comment: Could you include the code of the `AsyncFunction` in the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`await` is aware of a thing called `SynchronizationContext`. If such context is present (`SynchronizationContext.Current` is not null) then continuation after `await` is passed to that context, because it should know better how to handle it (unless you explicitly tell to not do that, using `await someTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`)

Most UI frameworks do not like when UI is accessed from multiple threads concurrently, because it often leads to various hard to debug problems. They utilize `SynchronizationContext` to enforce single flow of execution. To do that - they usually put callbacks posted to SynchronizationContext in some sort of queue, and execute them one by one on the single "UI" thread.

Blazor also does that. `GetAwaiterGetResultOnFunction` is your case is executed on that "UI" thread, with `SynchronizationContext` available. When execution reaches `await Task.Delay` inside `AsyncFunction` - current context is captured and it's noted that when `Task.Delay` completes - the rest of the function should be posted to the context for execution.

Then you block the "UI" thread by doing `GetResult` on a task returned from `AsyncFunction`. Then `Task.Delay` completes and the rest of the function is posted to the `SynchronizationContext` of Blazor to execute. However, to do that Blazor needs the same UI thread you just blocked, resulting in deadlock.

When you call `GetAwaiterGetResultOnTask` - `AsyncFunction` does not run on "UI" thread of Blazor - it runs on some other (thread pool) thread. `SynchronizationContext` is null, the part after `await Task.Delay` will run on some thread pool thread and will not require "UI" thread to complete. Then there is no deadlock.